# New Ajax call as Ajax success function

Tags: jquery

I am just picking up on using jquery and have managed to put the .ajax function into use to retrieve an an html page.

Now, the retrieved html page has a link to a css file and I want to grab that as well so that when the page is loaded, the css will be in the cache as well.

So my question essentially is that is it possible to run another ajax call as the success function and if so, is the config I am thinking of using (see code below) on the right track?

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    var ourPath;
    $('head link[rel="id_tag"]')
    .each(function() {
        ourPath = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: ourPath, 
            dataType: 'html',
            ifModified: true,
            success: function (html) {
                var dataURL;
                $(html).find('link[rel="stylesheet"]')
                .each(function() {
                    dataURL = $(this).attr('href');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: dataURL, 
                        dataType: 'text',
                        ifModified: true
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am particularly unsure about the `$(html).('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');` and `dataURL = $(this).attr('href');` lines (assuming the whole idea is feasible in the first place)

Comment: `$(this).attr('href') === this.href`

Comment: Can you pls clarify? Do you mean "dataURL = $(this).attr('href')" should be "dataURL = this.href"? I ask because "ourPath = $(this).attr('href');" works fine when I don't have the success function.

Comment: I'm just saying, don't use expensive jQuery methods to access native properties of a DOM element.  Your actual problem is that in your nested `success:` function, `this` is not the same as _outside_ that function.

Comment: Right, so you are saying I should use "this.href" instead of "$(this).attr('href')" to avoid Jquery calls. Got that. I'll look into that. On the scope of the different"this" instances, I would hope they they are indeed different as when outside, I want to refer to the elements of the current request and in the nested function, I want it to refer to the elements of the files retrieved by the ajax call. So that is not a problem but the desired outcome.

Comment: sure, but at no point in the nested `success` does `this` ever get set to the current `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag.  It's like you planned to use a `.each()` as you did on the outer call, but never actually did it.

Comment: Yes ... I missed out the "each" function ... I updated that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to update this.

What actually works reliably is:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    $('head link[rel="id_tag"]')
    .each(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href, 
            dataType: 'html',
            ifModified: true,
            success: function (html) {
                $(html).filter('link[rel="stylesheet"]')
                .each(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.href, 
                        dataType: 'text',
                        ifModified: true
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The key is `$(html).filter('link[rel="stylesheet"]')` in place of the suggested `$(html).find('link[rel="stylesheet"]')`.

The input given helped lead to the solution nonetheless.

Comment: bad form IMHO to mark this as the accepted answer when the (alleged) reason for your change couldn't have been discerned from the original question.  FWIW, if `.filter` works and `.find` doesn't then your supplied HTML is probably malformed.

Comment: I am sorry about any negative impact my action may have had on you but all I know is that this is what works for me. I am of course indebted to you and Jasper for leading me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This line is invalid, you need a function-name in front of the second selector:

```
$(html).('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');
```

Change To:

```
$(html).find('link[rel="stylesheet"]').each(function (index, obj) {
    $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" >').appendTo("head");
});
```

An AJAX call for the style-sheet is not necessary, you just need to append a `<link>` element to the `head` of the document with it's `href` attribute set to the `href` of the new style-sheet.

Comment: Sorry ... I was editing the question. Not sure if your answer is still consistent with it.

Comment: @Dayo I removed the part you fixed in your edit, what's in my answer is still valid.

Comment: Thanks. I can use this config for some other things but as for this specific one, I want to request the css file linked in the file being called so that it is cached. I.E., I absolutely need to make a call for the css file if this is possible.

Comment: @Dayo You don't need to make an AJAX call, if you append a `<link>` element to the DOM (like my example above) an HTTP request will be sent and the browser will cache the style-sheet (or retrieve it from  cache if possible). The only thing you lose using this method over an AJAX request is a callback function (well there are other options that you can set with `$.ajax` but they don't really apply to this situation).

Comment: Pls bear with me as I am new to this. I do not want to append the css link to the current file as it would mess that file up. This is why I want to make the Ajax call ... just to cache it for when the file called via the original ajax function is loaded. Basically, I am hell bent on making the Ajax call for this if possible so pls humour me if you can.  I will update the question with the setup as it stands and will appreciate your feedback if this approach is in any way possible. I appreciate your time on this.

Comment: @Dayo FWIW, previous tests have shown that links for images in an HTML string parsed by jQuery initiate downloads immediately even if the HTML string isn't inserted into the DOM at that point.  I expect that holds for `<link>` tags too.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good use of jQuery's `deferred` objects, which avoids the need to nest the AJAX calls.

```
function get(href, type) {
     return $.ajax({url: href, dataType: type, ifModified: true});
};

// find the snippet(s) to download
$('head link[rel="my_tag"]).each(function() {
    get(this.href, 'html')
    .done(function(html) {
        $(html).find('link[rel="stylesheet"]).each(function() {
            get(this.href, 'text');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the help from both of you and believe I have moved forward a lot as a result but is there a specific problem with the nested approach I want to follow? I ask because you have both given me alternative approaches but haven't specifically said whether there is an issue with the nested approach. If there isn't, can you pls look at the updated code in the question and help take me across the line on that basis? I want to follow that approach and will appreciate your help in doing so ... except of course if there is an issue with the whole nested approach itself. Thanks.

Comment: @Dayo the nested approach is fine, but can lead to more convoluted code than is necessary.  I've shown the deferred method because since jQuery 1.5 that's now the better way.

Comment: I accepted your answer and also gave Jasper a vote up for his input. My thanks to both of you.